# LeetCode 384 - Shuffle an Array [Python], Why do we use "list(self.nums)"

Tags: python

```
import random

class Solution(object):
    def __init__(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type size: int
        """
        self.nums = nums

    def reset(self):
        """
        Resets the array to its original configuration and return it.
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        return self.nums

    def shuffle(self):
        """
        Returns a random shuffling of the array.
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        ret = list(self.nums)
        random.shuffle(ret)
        return ret
```

Why do we use `ret = list(self.nums)`? I tried to use `ret = left.nums`, but it doesn't pass through the LeetCode solution. I don't understand why we put `list()` in front of `self.nums`. My guess is that `self.nums` is already a list.

Comment: Maybe using `self.nums.copy()` instead of `list(self.nums)` would carry more "meaning" while doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Calling [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html?highlight=list#list) here will *create a copy* of `self.nums` (see [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2612802/78845) ):

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> x = l
>>> l.append(4)
>>> x, l
([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> y = list(l)
>>> l.append(5)
>>> y, l
([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

This means that `shuffle()` leaves the underlying list of numbers untouched while returning a shuffled list (since [`random.shuffle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) shuffles the input *in place*).

Keeping this list untouched allows the `reset()` method to work.

Comment: Then, why do we need to create a copy here in this question? "ret = left.nums" should be working as well.

Comment: you could _explicitly_ mention that `random.shuffle` works in-place that's why one needs the copy.

Comment: @Jianlei'John'Sun: I've updated my answer to try to highlight "why".

Answer (score 0):

`ret = list(self.nums)` creates a new list since shuffle does a in place shuffle. So `ret` holds a copy of the original list which gets shuffled and returned and `self.nums` holds the contents of the original list.